# Parameter estimation using convolutional for exponential functions

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model

I was inspired by [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-019-0148-5) where the authors fed an 1-dimenisonal input waveform to the simple convolutional neural network and got an estimate of four parameters of the analytic model. This inspired me to see if I could use CNNs to estimate parameters of more complex analytic models.

I have a complex non-linear (contains exponential and Bessel functions) set of equations that depend on five parameters:

1. v1 = 0.1  -> 5
2. v2 = 1e3  -> 1e4
3. v2 = 1e3  -> 1e4
4. v4 = 0.01 -> 0.5
5. v5 = 0.01 -> 1.0

The output waveform is exponential and can vary 4-6 orders of magnitude over the observed time period.

I generated around 200K sample waveforms and the parameter values used to generate them. I construct the following network in Tensorflow:

> Model: "sequential_1"
> _____ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
> ===== conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 376, 128)          2048
> _____ conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 372, 64)           41024
> _____ dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 372, 512)          33280
> _____ dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 372, 512)          262656
> _____ dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 372, 512)          262656
> _____ dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 372, 512)          262656
> _____ flatten (Flatten)            (None, 190464)            0
> _____ dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 512)               97518080
> _____ dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 512)               262656
> _____ dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 2565
> ===== Total params: 98,647,621 Trainable params: 98,647,621 Non-trainable
> params: 0
>
> ---

When I go to train the network I noticed that the accuracy remains low and loss is large. When I go to predict parameters I notice that I get a rough (~20% difference between predicted and actual) estimate for v2/v3 but the rest of the variables are 0. This leads me to believe that the issue is the many orders of magnitude difference between the input and different outputs.

Hence, I did the following, I normalized the data by taking the logarithm of the input curve to ensure the input is <20. I also took the logarithm of the parameters and added a constant bias so the parameters (network output) are all 0-3. This time when I trained the network, the accuracy was even worse!

I tried a couple different networks and normalizations but so far nothing has shown any promise. So now I'm wondering if any of you guys has an ideas? Should I be trying a different kind of NN (other than CNN)? **Is there something I can do to have the NN more amenable to handling exponentially varying inputs/outputs**?

Finally **does anyone know of any papers that does parameter estimation of exponential analytic functions**? The one I linked fits a linear function and I think the complexity might be the major issue here.

Comment: Can you add a normalisation layer?